# Split string into two levels

Tags: bash

I have the following string

```
my_str="A:Apple|B:Ball|C:Cat"
```

and I want to echo the following

```
A for Apple
B for Ball
C for Cat
```

The code I use is

```
IFS="|"
delimiter=':'
my_str="A:Apple|B:Ball|C:Cat"
for pair in ${my_str}; do
  #echo "${pair}"
  s=$pair$delimiter
  var1=${s%%"$delimiter"*}
  var2=${s#*"$delimiter"}
  echo "${var1} for ${var2}"
done
```

But the output I get is

```
A for Apple:
B for Ball:
C for Cat:
```

Could someone help me remove the extra delimiter appended at the end?

Comment: Try `${pair}` without appending `${delimiter}` like `s=${pair}`.

Answer (score 5):

bash's `read` provides an option (`-d`) for customizing the line delimiter, you can use it in conjunction with `IFS`.

```
while IFS=':' read -r -d '|' k v; do
    printf '%s for %s\n' "$k" "$v"
done <<< ${my_str%|}'|'
```

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
echo "$my_str" | awk -F'|' '{gsub(/:/," for ");for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i}}'
```

***2nd solution:*** Using `gsub` fair warning, written and tested with shown samples only.

```
echo "$my_str" | awk '{gsub(/:/," for ");gsub(/\|/,"\n")} 1'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
A for Apple
B for Ball
C for Cat
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two calls to `read`: one to split the line into an array, the other to split each element of the array.

```
my_str="A:Apple|B:Ball|C:Cat"

IFS="|" read -a pairs <<< "$my_str"
for pair in "${my_str[@]}"; do
    IFS=: read letter object <<< "$pair"
    printf '%s for %s\n' "$letter" "$object"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu-awk`:

```
awk -F ':|\n' -v RS='|' '{print $1, "for", $2}' <<< "$my_str"
```

```
A for Apple
B for Ball
C for Cat
```

For POSIX `awk`, use this:

```
awk -F '[:|]' 'NF%2 == 0{for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i, "for", $(i+1)}' <<< "$my_str"
```

Comment: What if I want to store A and Apple in separate variables and then print them?

Comment: You can store them in simple variable or associative array in awk